# Stomp client for Objective C Doesn't Connect

Tags: objective-c, client, stomp

I am attempting to integrate the Stomp Objective-C client into a rather simple application, using the directions given at http://dev.coravy.com/wiki/display/OpenSource/Stomp+client+for+Objective-C.

My app compiles fine, but when I try to connect to a host, I get no response. After breakpointing through the STOMP code, I find that this call at AsyncSocket.m:3641 always returns NO:

```
    return CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(theWriteStream);
```

I'd appreciate any help on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the STOMP code is working fine. I didn't get a response because the STOMP server was not responding due to a setup error.